# 404 Error after Renaming Controller, View & Default Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I'm getting a *404 Page Not Found* error in CodeIgniter\WAMP after doing the following:

1. renamed a controller (from *welcome.php* to *search.php*)
2. renamed the view to load from search.php as *search_page* (see below)
3. renamed the related view (from *welcome_message.php* to *search_page.php*)
4. renamed the default controller in config\routes.php to search
5. restarted WAMP

**search.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('search_page');
}
```

**config\routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "search";
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have renamed the `Controller Class Name` too, make sure>

Comment: Oh no I did not, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not a codeigniter programmer, but you should make the class Search -> `class Search extends CI_Controller`, no? found it on this link -> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

i think it's the same in every framework, cakephp, codeigniter, zend etc.